# how we update users from postman using PUT method when we use rest api of users in cs-cart

Tags: cs-cart

how we update users from postman using PUT method when we use rest api of users in cs-cart

i'm using cs-cart rest api it is working for GET and DELETE method properly but i dint in case of PUT and POST method , how we send parameter or data

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Please check the following documentation:

http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/developer_guide/api/entities/users.html

Do not forget to change request type to "Put" and use the "JSON (application/json)" data type